# Python 3 syntax should work, but doesn't

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, syntax

It's so basic it should work. I want a function that adds a value to something

There must be something I don't know about python 3, so here we go.

```
x = 0

def foo(x=x): ##### with out x=x there is a error
    x = x + 1   # option one
    x = 1       # option two

# when we run it
foo()

print(x)
# it returns 0, it should return 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a *local* variable in `foo()`; Assigning `x` as a default value for a keyword argument won't make it any less a local.

If you wanted it to be a global, mark it as such:

```
x = 0

def foo():
    global x
    x = x + 1

print(x)
foo()
print(x)
```

but you probably just wanted to pass in the value as an argument instead:

```
def foo(value):
    return value + 1

x = 0
print(x)
x = foo(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically and example of scoping rules. The variable x within foo is local to foo, so nothing that happens to the local x changes anything outside foo, including the global x with which is actually a different variable. When the interpreter exits foo the global x comes back into scope and it hasn't changed from its initial value of 0. The function header foo(x=x) defines a local x whose default value is the global x. The interpreter allows it but it's generally considered bad programming practice to have the same variable name representing two variables because it leads to this kind of confusion.